# XSL modifying the href attribute of an html <a> tag

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I am rather new to XSLT and was wondering how I can modify the href attribute of a  tag with a value acquired from an XML node.

In particular, my XML file goes like this

```
<root>
<privileges edit="1" del="1"></privileges> 
<rooms> 
<room> 
<id>1</id> 
<roomNr>101</roomNr> 
<locked>0</locked> 
<lockdownReason></lockdownReason> 
</room>
</rooms>
</root>
```

and my XSL file goes like

```
<xsl:for-each select="root/rooms/room">
<div class="column toolbox">
<xsl:if test="$edit = 1">
<a href='admin.php?room=VALUE_OF_ID__OF_CURRENTLY_SELECTED_NODE'>this is a link</a>
<p>edit is true</p>
</xsl:if>
</div>
<div class="column">Room Nr.:<xsl:value-of select="roomNr"/></div>
</xsl:for-each>
```

the capital letters indicate what I try to accomplish.
Someone please be kind enough to reply.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your XSLT, the easiest thing would be to use an [Attribute Value Template (AVT)](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#dt-attribute-value-template) and select the value of `<id>`, like this:

```
<a href='admin.php?room={id}'>this is a link</a>
```

Comment: +1 this was news to me, a lot more convenient than `xsl:attribute`. Thanks!

Comment: Nice one! Thanks a million xD

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [xsl:attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/XSL/el_attribute.asp). I'm not really sure about how the reference to the current `id` should look, but something like this should get you started:

```
<a>
<xsl:attribute name="href">admin.php?room=<xsl:value-of select="./id"/></xsl:attribute>
this is a link
</a>
```